# Integration of logarithm

Tags: calculus, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

$\int \ln(\ln \sqrt{x})^{\ln (x)}dx$ how should I integrate this? I think it can't be integrated. I don't know.

Comment: By writing the integrand this way, you are expressing ignorance about the properties of the logarithm that may make this integral doable.  In fact, this integral is very doable.

Answer (score 0):

The integral can be transformed into some easy-integrate parts and the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\ln x}$ by integration by parts. But the latter has no closed form. For details see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li(x). Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

$$I = \int \ln(\ln \sqrt{x})^{\ln x} dx$$
$$ = \int \ln \left(\ln \left(x^{1/2}\right) \right)^{\ln x} dx$$
$$ = \int \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln x \right)^{\ln x} dx$$
$$= \int (\ln x) \cdot \ln \left(\frac{1}{2}\ln x \right) dx$$
$$ = \int (\ln x) \cdot \left(\ln \frac{1}{2} + \ln x \right) dx$$

Let $$u = \ln x$$, $$x = e^u$$, $$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$$, $$x = x du = e^u du$$

Therefore,

$$I = \int u \left( \ln \frac{1}{2} + u \right) e^u du$$
$$ = \int \left( \ln \frac{1}{2} \cdot u e^u + u^2 e^u \right) du$$
which can be integrated by parts.